# How do I determine the DC which a remote Exchange server is using?

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Using C# I want to determine which DC (or at least which Site) the Exchange Server I am programming against is using.

I have a "User creation tool"  and if it creates the user on a DC on the local site and then tries to enable the user on a DC in the Exchange server's site (Exchange 2010 remote ps cmdlet) it will error with the "object not found" since replication hasn't happened. If I ensure that I get the same DC as the server, then I won't have that problem.

basically a C# way of doing nltest /DSGETDC on the remote exchange server would be perfect

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the native API [DsGetDcName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675983%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from C# using [pinvoke code](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/DsGetDcName.html).

Comment: Looks like this might do it.  It seems I can tell it the computer to ask and all.  Thanks!